# Implementing a goal without a "thank you page"

Tags: google-analytics

I'm fairly new to goals and events in GA.

I'd like some help implementing goals tracking.
I have a simple landing page that is located on my subdomain folder.

campaign.mydomain.com the page is php and contains and simple name and phone fields. I would like to measure my performance. when I submit the form inside the landing page, I get this URL http://campaign.example.com/index.php?action=thanks

The GA tracking code on my landing page:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXX-1', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

My form code is: 
index.php-

```
                        <form class="contact-form" name="contactForm" action="javascript:void(0);">
                            <div class="input-block">
                                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name"/>
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="input-block">
                                <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Mobile"/>
                                <span class="error"></span>
                            </div>
                            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit"/> 
                        </form>
```

and I have an additional JS file that handles errors and send the form data to my CRM:
here's the last part of it

```
    success: function (elm) {

        var dataGet = { m_form: "10219", m_key: "2c33b4325aca4f898e89cc81f94b655b", name: name.val(), phone: phone.val() };

        $.get( "http://api.crm.im/v1/submit", dataGet );

        $.get("http://example.com/index.php?pathAjax=pages/ajax/minisite_contact.php", dataGet );

        window.location = "index.php?action=thanks";
```

I cannot setup a conversion due to thank you page missing. any help would be appricated !

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set Goals for Events (instead of Pages). The only thing you need to do is send an event after success.

To send events to GA you can call `ga('send', 'event', <Category>, <Action>, <Label>)`
In your case you can use:

```
    success: function (elm) {
      ga('send', 'event', 'Landing Page', 'Submit');
          (...)
```

Then you just need to create a Goal based on the event and you're good to go.

Go to Admin > Goals (under the view)

Select Custom > Type = Event

Category = "Landing Page" and Action = "Submit" (leave Label and Value empty)

Sending Events in GA: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events

Visual app to send events to GA without coding: http://www.popcornmetrics.com/

Comment: Wow, such an informative post, thank you !
I wanted to test your solution and now i see my GA goals conversion actually went up (using this link as the thank you page "http://campaign.example.com/index.php?action=thanks" although this page dosen't really exist.. does it really takes a couple of hours/minutes to render the data since the actual submit on client side ?

Comment: If you open Real Time (left tab) > Conversions, you can see Goals showing in real time. To see in reports (anything not in the Real Time tab) you need to wait since it takes some hours for Google to process the data.